# Deploying multiple contracts with different solc versions

Tags: truffle, solc

I have a few contracts that I deploy with my 1_initial_migration.js. However some of them are of different solc version than others. Is there a way to change it programmatically before compiling and then change it back for other contracts in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around this by creating a *no_compile* folder in the root directory and moving there all the contracts that need another solc version. Then compiling them separately by providing a different solc version in the *truffle-config.js*